# Cannot interact with all the textviews in the screen using robotium

Tags: java, android, robotium, instrumentation

I am facing a weird problem using robotium, when i use, `solo.getCurrentViews()` I get the views in a screen. But for some activities thought the views are loaded, i cannot see the views on the screen, they are hidden and some user actions needed to show them. For example, in Amazon home screen, i have to scroll through the product list, only 3 products are shown in the initial screen. But `solo.getCurrentViews()` loads all the product views. Now if say I click TextViews other than the three text views that are shown on the screen I get an error and the application exits. So, i think I have to somehow examine whether the textview is currently visible on the screen or not. This goes for all view objects. 
Robotium loads all the views, but clicking views which are not currently visible causes error.

Answer (score 1):

The `Solo.getCurrentViews()` will return all the views. 
You can use: `RobotiumUtils.removeInvisibleViews(solo.getCurrentViews())` for filtering the visible views.

OR  you can filter the visible TextViews by yourself using the following code.

```
public ArrayList<TextView> getFilteredTextViews()
{
       ArrayList<TextView> textViewList = solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class);
       ArrayList<TextView> filteredTextViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        for (TextView textview : textViewList ) {
            if (textview != null && textview.isShown()) 
                        {
                filteredTextViewList .add(view);
            }
        }
        return filteredTextViewList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast every view to its class (or to android.view class!) and then check its "VISIBLE" property.

For TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) solo.getCurrentViews().get(i);
int visible = tv.VISIBLE;
```

0 - Visible on screen; the default value.
1 - Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
2 - Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

Do the same for all the controls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved it with the isShown() property of the view objects.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to let you know, I solved the problem by using view.isShown() method check.